# Why does Spring return an object without previous change?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring jpa and something weird is happening. I have a `JpaRepository` repository and there is an update that I did inside the **service**, right after I need to get the new object and use it.

The problem is that after calling `updateValue`, the `findById` still returns the old state. Like the call to `updateValue` wasn't committed or something.

By running an integration test, it returns the new value. And after the whole transaction, the new value shows up.

```
repository.updateValue(productId, 
repository.findById
```

Why the `findById` is not returning the updated object?

Comment: What is your `updateValue` doing? That isn't a default method from Spring Data JPA and probably has to do with how you are updating stuff. Generally you should be using `save` and not update individual values yourself as that would probably bypass the first level cache.

Comment: The comment from the other guy helped me. I added an EntityManager and I call entityManager.refresh(entity) and it get the updated one.

Comment: Which basically already indicates that you are updating in a way you shouldn't be updating your entitites.

Comment: Why is that? I mean. I need to update them but need to be in separate queries inside one transaction